# Rendering raw Html sources in React using doesn't show the body style of the sources

Tags: html, reactjs

to render some HTML sources in React, I use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml`.

The problem, the body style of the Html sources doesn't show as we expected.

For example: let's say we have this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p><a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p>
<p>The bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to render this html code, the `bgcolor` doesn't show as we expected.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym3q5yy2nj)

[demo 2](https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/cb4bb492)

Comment: The real problem is that you cannot really put a `doctype` declaration nor a `html` or `body` tag inside a div. And the `#root` element is a `div` in which you try to render a full html document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actully able to see the `bgcolor` in action on the "**demo 2**" Sample.

But for a good practices you should apply CSS styling through dedicated style element (`<style></style>`) as follow:

```
<head><style>body{background-color: #E6E6FA;}</style></head>
```

So a working example of the sample code will be:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const htmlString =
  "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{background-color:#E6E6FA;}</style></head><body><h1>Hel1lo world!</h1><p><a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p><p>The bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p></body></html>";

const App = () => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/1q0781w5ml

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can not changed the given html content. In your way, I need to edit the content inserting "style" tag.

Answer (score 1):

**"root"** is already inside the document body of a page that has already been rendered, not an empty page. So you're rendering a new page inside a page that already has a HEAD etc.

You may want to change this to be rendered in an iframe, depending on your goal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It makes sense.